# htaccess. give a 410 error and redirect dynamic php page

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Google in error has indexed thousands of urls that are not in the sitemap.xml. These urls probably are considered as duplicate content (according to Google only).

I would need to deindex them fairly quickly. So would a 410 gone status would be handy.

in htaccess i would like to redirect

```
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=1&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=2&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=3&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=5&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=6&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=7&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=8&page=xxx
www.domain.com/page.php?bid=9&page=xxx
```

to this page

www.domain.com/page.php?bid=4&page=xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^bid=[1-35-9]&page=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.php)$ /$1?bid=4&page=%1 [L,R=301]
```

`301` (permanent redirect) will force Google to update its cached results.

Comment: the code worked perfect. how could we alter the last line with more pages examples like this   

    page_xx.php   page_bbb.php    page_cccc.php

Comment: by your example i can alter like this to work like magic RewriteRule ^page_([^&]+)\.php$ $0?bid=4&page=%1 [L,R=301]

Comment: You can use: `RewriteRule ^page_([^.]+)\.php$`